# Find QObject which is not a child

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++/QML application with one C++ `QObject` from which I want to change a  tray icon. The tray icon is created in `main.cpp` since it requires the root object of the `QQmlApplicationEngine` for this.

My `main.cpp` looks something like this:

```
qmlRegisterType<Model>("Model", 1,0, "Model");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QObject *root = 0;
if (engine.rootObjects().size() > 0)
{
    root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
    [...]
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(root);
    trayIcon->setObjectName("TrayIcon");
    [...]
}
```

And I have a `QObject` named Model which I instantiate from within the QML code.

Everything works fine but now I want to change the tray icon's icon from the model. It seems my model does not have a parent and my idea was to get the tray icon by giving it an `objectName` and searching for it again in my model. But how can I search for it if I can't get to the root object and the tray icon is also not a child of me?

Comment: You can't find it if it is not in the root object tree. Follow Kuba's advice and expose it as a context property.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the `QSystemTrayIcon` to QML just as you would any other object. Most likely, you can add the tray icon as a root context property to QML.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. I don't want to access the TrayIcon from Qml but from my QObject instance. How can I search for it from there?

Comment: @Fabian Since you instantiate the QObject from QML, then QML must know about the tray icon instance. Hence you pass it into QML, and then out of QML when it instantiates the object.

Comment: A small sample app is now here: https://github.com/sturmf/qt_samples/tree/master/trayicon I now used a global variable to pass the rootObject to the model instance. But this is really messy. Maybe you can have a look and tell me how to improve the code. I also once had a version where I registered the QSystemTrayIcon class for QML and instantiated it there but this only seems to work half, as I e.g. can't create QIcons in QMl and the onActivated signal handler does not receive the reason argument...